# angular2 project content to different template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am new to Angular and have started with a simple tab example.
I have tabs that display and hide content on click.  The content however is displayed directly below the tabs.  I want the content to be in a different template.  How can I project the content to the other template?

This is my tab component it currently outputs the content of the tab in ng-content tags.

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {TabsComponent} from './tabs.component';

@Component ({
    selector: 'tab',
    template: `
                <div [hidden]="!active" class="widget-tab-content">
                    <ng-content></ng-content>
                </div>
              `
})
export class TabComponent {

    @Input() tabtitle: string;

    constructor(tabs: TabsComponent) {
        tabs.addTab(this);
    }
```

and this is the template for another component where I want the tab content to be inserted

```
<div id="incident_overview" class="pane-container" style="">
<div id="incident_overview_handle" class="pane-handle" style="">
<i style="margin-right: 10px;" class="fa fa-ticket" aria-hidden="true"></i>Generic Widget
<div class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;">
<i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<!--<ul data-widget-id="incident_overview" id="widget_incident_history-tabs" class="pane-tabs nav nav-tabs pull-right" style="font-size: 12px;">
<li value="0" class="active"><a href="">Overview</a></li>
<li value="1" class=""><a href="">Incident</a></li>
<li value="2" class=""><a href="">Email</a></li>
<li value="3" class=""><a href="">Resolution</a></li>
</ul>-->
<tabs>
    <tab tabtitle="Overview">1</tab>
    <tab tabtitle="Incident">2</tab>
    <tab tabtitle="Email">3</tab>
    <tab tabtitle="Resolution">4</tab>
</tabs>

</div>
<div class="pane normal-pane table-pane ui-widget-content">
<div id="widget_content" class="widget-table-pane">
    **** I WANT THE TAB CONTENTS TO BE DISPLAYED HERE****

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Apologies I appreciate this is a noob question

Comment: You're already using the `<tab>` componentes a few lines above. What are you trying to achieve in `#widget_content`?

Comment: the <tab> components have the title of the tab and the content.  The tabComponent adds any tab tags to a list and then displays the titles.

I want to use the content from the <tag> Component and display it in the #widget_content.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/1bwD17KvSsgrkCGe9sic

I have added my files to plunker, FYI it may not work in here yet but you can at least see better what I am trying to do I hope.